# How do I use the old javadoc style / theme with JDK 7?

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

The new theme in JDK 7 for javadoc is hard for me to read. It may not be pretty but I really would prefer the old theme. Aside from installing the old JDK and switching between them, can I somehow use the old doclet?

Comment: You're not the only one. The color for the links is so close to the normal text color in my eyes that I can't easily distinguish linkes from normal text. And they didn't underline them either. Maybe it's my (light) color-blindness, but I find the new theme less usable than the old one.

Comment: In firefox, in old javadoc you could search for a class by typing / ClassName (note the leading space after the quickfind character '/').  This is now broken (the bottom left pane no longer includes a space after each class name, which made this possible).  I desperately need this back!

Answer (score 5):

Have to admit I haven't experienced this yet, but I've found that you can customize the CSS for the java doc. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/enhancements-7.html) is the description.

You might be interested in running this:

```
C:> javadoc -stylesheetfile C:\user\exampleStylesheet.css com.examplePackage
```

Its also stated there that it creates 'stylesheet.css' file so you should see how it looks like and what can be overridden there.

Hope this helps

Comment: Maybe I can just copy/paste an old stylesheet.css

Comment: i dont think copypasting will work, the two default css look completely different, the 7 style is a lot more flexible, more semantic and more compliant to current standards. You should definitely override it as explained above its a lot easier than with java 6

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a late answer, but someone has developed a stylesheet that can be used to get the old pre-7 rendering:

http://junk-box.appspot.com/stylesheet/classic-javadoc-stylesheet/index.html

I too do not like the newer post-6 style, it is less readable and harder to scan.  I prefer readability over visual aesthetic.

Comment: Late but still appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it bothers you that much and you don't want to mess around with stylesheets and templates, you can always install JDK 1.6 in another directory and use its Javadoc util instead.

Comment: This is feasible but I would expect there is a simple switch to continue to use the old style, if one wants.

Comment: "Aside from installing the old JDK"

Answer (score -1):

I can't say I've tried with Java 7, but [yDoc](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_ydoc.html) is a neat customizable [doclet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doclet). Besides adding class diagrams (maybe they can be filtered out), I think it's still possible to generate the javadoc with the *original style*.

There is a free version available (I'm not related to yWorks, I just happened to write taglets and used yDoc).

Comment: Ouch! For thinking it was more about the theme than the doclet, somehow.