# How do I generate JDK 7 api docs as HTML tables rather than CSS for display in emacs-w3m

Tags: java, emacs, javadoc, w3m

JDK 6 api javadocs use HTML tables for layout.

These tables display nicely in `emacs-w3m`, which means I can browse api docs without leaving the emacs.

[image: JDK 6 API docs in w3m]

JDK 7 api javadocs use CSS for layout.

This renders this top menu bar as a `<ul>` which displays vertically due (presumably) to w3m not understanding the CSS. This means that the first page or so of text is wasted.

[image: JDK 7 API docs in w3m]

I'd like to render the JDK 7 api docs in the style of JDK 6, so I am hoping to use the JDK 6 doclet to (re)generate the JDK 7 docs using HTML tables. Since this is a one off operation I'm not concerned about inefficiencies etc.

But how do I specify the JDK 6 doclet to use?

Comment: Have you tried simply installing JDK6, and using its javadoc tool on the sources of JDK7? Or using a real IDE? I used to be a fan of Emacs, but this was 15 years ago. IDEs are much much more productive than emacs nowadays.

Comment: javadoc from jdk6 refused to generate anything when pointed at jdk7 source, lots of errors, not sure if it's fixable. Turns out it was easier to just remove the offending ``<ul>`` from the generated html with some ``awk`` hackery.

Comment: Javadoc uses a part of the compiler, the language evolved from 6 to 7, and the JDK likely uses lots of the new language features. You might be able to use the standard doclet from java 6 with javadoc 7, but I'm not totally sure of this.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839580/how-do-i-use-the-old-javadoc-style-theme-with-jdk-7